# Why do I get error parsing with my dynamo_db_table_name with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am running `terraform init` in my bootstrap folder

```
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 mm mm 4096 Nov 20 10:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 mm mm 4096 Nov 20 10:33 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 mm mm  370 Nov 20 10:35 bootstrap_callModule.tf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mm mm  482 Nov 20 10:43 bootstrap_dynamodb_table.tf
-rw-r--r-- 1 mm mm  457 Nov 20 10:34 bootstrap_providers.tf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mm mm  560 Nov 20 10:42 bootstrap_s3_bucket.tf
```

I have error parsing

```
bootstrap_dynamodb_table.tf: At 2:10: Unknown token: 2:10 IDENT var.dynamo_db_table_name
```

bootstrap_dynamodb_table.tf

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "tf_lock_state" {
  name = var.dynamo_db_table_name

  # Pay per request is cheaper for low-i/o applications, like our TF lock state
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"

  # Hash key is required, and must be an attribute
  hash_key = "LockID"

  # Attribute LockID is required for TF to use this table for lock state
  attribute {
    name = "LockID"
    type = "S"
  }

  tags = {
    Name    = var.dynamo_db_table_name
    BuiltBy = "Terraform"
  }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What version of Terraform are you using?

Comment: Terraform v0.11.11,it seems it is out of date.

Comment: Yeah you're using HCL2 syntax that was introduced in 0.12. You need to interpolate it with `"${var.dynamo_db_table_name}"` instead in 0.11 and below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is after Terraform v0.12. (Without "" AND ${}).

Please follow the syntax below if your Terraform version less v0.12.

```
tags = {
    Name    = "${var.dynamo_db_table_name}"
    BuiltBy = "Terraform"
  }
```

Comment: This is the most simple and accurate answer I've found anywhere. Thanks, man.